# twitter4j - What is the relation between Tweet and Status?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

What is the relation between these two? Is there a way to deduce one from another?

The context: Why it's possible to search only for "Tweet"s and listen only to a stream of "Status"es?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In twitter4j *2.25* there is a 'Tweet' class

```
/** A data class representing a Tweet in the search response
Author(s):
Yusuke Yamamoto - yusuke at mac.com **/

public interface Tweet extends Comparable<Tweet>, EntitySupport,
        java.io.Serializable {
    ...
}
```

while StatusListener provides access to instances of 'Status' class

```
public interface StatusListener extends StreamListener {
    void onStatus(Status status);
    ...
}
```

They are basically the same but not interoperable.
In twitter4j 3.0.3 there is no 'Tweet' class

Answer (score 1):

The are notionally the same thing.  I am not sure where you see search for Tweets in the Twitter4j api, I only see statuses.

I think the concept here is that the action is tweet, and the object that you tweet is a status.

People have objectified tweeting so that in common parlance people say that they 'tweeted a tweet', but actually they should have said they 'tweeted a status'